# Finding $m$ such that $f(x) = x^2+2mx+m^2+1$ satisfies $f(\Im_f)=\Im_f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

Problem:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^2+2mx+m^2+1$.
>   Find $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\Im_f) = \Im_f$, where $\Im_f$ indicates the image of $f$.

My question is, what's the actual condition for $f(\Im_f) = \Im_f$ ?

I'm confused.

Comment: By $\Im_f$ do you mean the image of $f$?

Comment: Yes, that's \Im_f , image of f.

Comment: The image of $f$ is the set $f(\mathbb{R})$. That is all the points $f$ can possibly map to in $\mathbb{R}$. So, $f(\Im_f)$ is the set of all points $f$ can map points in $\Im_f$. In particular then, we are searching for an $m$ such that $f(f(\mathbb{R}))=f(\mathbb{R})$ since $f(\mathbb{R})$ is the image of $f$. Note that this is not the same as requiring that $f(f(x))=f(x)$. We are only seeking set equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=(x+m)^2+1\geq 1$, so $f(\mathbb{R})=[1,\infty)$. If we want $f([1,\infty))=[1,\infty)$, $(x+m)^2$ must equal zero for some $x\in [1,\infty)$, i.e. $f(x)$ has a minimum on $[1,\infty)$. This can only happen if $m\leq -1$.